# How can the value of the "Quantity" field in bill of material lines be copied to the field "Height" during data entry?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

When editing bill of material (BOM) lines, the value of field "Quantity" should be copied to field "Height". How can this be achieved?

See also the following two pictures:

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=205252BOM1.jpg
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=282509BOM2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table you are looking for is called `BOM`.

"Quantity" field is called `BOMQty`.

"Height" field is called `dim1`.

Both `BOMQty` and `dim1` are of type `real`, so there should not be any real issues initializing the values. The main question is **WHEN** do you need to initialize "Height" field.
For learning purposes, try playing with this code:

```
BOM BOM; //Table buffer
ttsBegin;
while select forUpdate BOM
{
    BOM.dim1 = BOM.BOMQty;
    BOM.update();       
}
ttsCommit;
```

For just updating the field once, I would suggest using [update_recordset](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aeremenk/archive/2007/04/17/2161619.aspx)

For initializing the height upon line creation, add this line to `BOM.insert()` method, before calling `super()`:

```
this.dim1 = this.BOMQty;
```

Comment: Thank you Maxim for your reply
I want initialize "Height" field when the user adds a new line in BOM
when it inserts the quantity (for example 0.5) this quantity will be put into "Height" field

Comment: Just add this line to `BOM.insert()` method before calling `super()`:     `this.dim1 = this.BOMQty;`

Comment: Also, consider using `modifiedField` of BOM, as the use will see the height change immediately.